# Upload Folder with Putty/SSH

Tags: ssh, putty, upload

I want to upload a folder (including subfolders and files) to a remote machine.

I can connect with putty via SSH.

How can I upload my folder? What is the easiest way to do so?

EDIT: How about a tool for Linux?

Answer (score 9):

[Winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) - It has a two pane interface, and works fairly simply. Just remember to pick scp as your protocol.

Answer (score 5):

If you have SSH, you also have SCP (Secure CoPy)

It is a fantastic tool for [copying files](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).  Its a very simple syntax as well.

If your not CLI inclined, Putty also has a tool called [PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

Comment: +1, although PuTTY's PSCP is a command line utility.

Comment: @Mike Fitzpatrik, sorry, I thought it was.. your right, I have been using WinSCP for so long with putty, I just thought it was the putty tool! oops.  Bonus points for the Journeyman geek!

Answer (score 3):

For Linux, you can use the scp command line tool which connects via the same interface as ssh. To send the entire local directory foo including sub directories, use a commandline like

```
scp -r localfolder username@remoteserver:
```

This would upload localfolder to your home directory on remoteserver